# Intelligent email campaigns with SalesForce

Tags: email, leads, campaign, email2lead, mail-chimp

I'm wondering if I can get some help in the email campaigns & newsletter topic:

We want to implement some automations regarding **newsletter subscriber TO hot-lead** conversions, and I'm curious if all of this is doable with SalesForce alone (without the use of an external service like MailChimp)

There will be various **SIGN UP TO OUR NEWSLETTER** buttons on our site, on various pages, and each of these buttons will add a user to a certain subscription list (a group), of a certain topic (regarding a certain product).

Then we will send out the specific newsletter to this person, and will try to get them to sign out a form to get more of their personal data (email, phone number, job title etc.) If we get this data, the person should become a **Lead** in SalesForce, so our Sales Representatives can start working with them.

Is this a "basic" automation that is already doable with SalesForce, or can you guys recommend any other external tool to achieve this?

NOTE: We installed **MailChimp for SalesForce**, but we're having issues setting it up, so we're in the process of fixing it with their support team. (Not a very good start, so that's why we're looking for alternatives)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really four choices:

## Basic Marketing

Using Campaigns, Web-to-Lead, and the built-in Mass Email feature, you can get started. However, this only works up to about 1,000 emails daily and less than 500 new leads a day. It would allow you to get by in a pinch, but you'll eventually have to step up to something better.

## Build Your Own

This is Salesforce! You could build your own project from the ground up, assuming you had the money and time to do so. I only include this option for completeness, as it's probably not something most organizations would do.

## Marketing Cloud

Marketing Cloud is an extra feature you can subscribe to, from salesforce.com directly. It supports all of your use cases and more, including lead capture, custom landing pages, sending emails, a/b email testing, and so on. I don't know what the price even starts at, but you can ask your Account Executive or Sales if MC is right for you.

## AppExchange

There's [nearly 600 services](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxSearchKeywordResults?keywords=email%20marketing) to choose from! MailChimp definitely isn't the only service out there. I suggest you pick a few, do some research, and then try one out. You can probably get either a trial or a demo. With so many choices, it can be a bit daunting, but I definitely recommend doing your homework.

---

Note: We're not really a *product recommendation service*. You will need to do your own research and arrive at your own conclusions. We do use Marketing Cloud where I'm at, but I've never used it for more than a few minutes, so I definitely am not qualified to recommend or not MC or any other AppExchange product.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox ! This is an awesome response, and I'm thankful for the work you're putting into your responses on this stack exchange!
I think the Basic Marketing might work for us, since the product has a smaller niche. Then maybe we can even build our own solutions on top of that.

Comment: @Laureant Yeah, the latent capability is there, and can be expanded with some effort. If you're small enough to meet that situation, then I'd go with what's already in the system. You'll find all the stuff you need in the documentation, a few quick searches is all it should take to get started.